Geometric Morphisms and Fibrations in Higher Category Theory
I have been exposed to the idea of geometric morphisms in an ordinary categorical sense. There is a paper titled 'Fibred categories a la Jean Benabou' this somewhat links geometric morphisms and fibrations (Do not understand it). Given a continuous functor $\mathcal{F} \colon \mathcal{E} \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}$ such that for any functor $\mathcal{U}$ fully faithful with $\mathcal{U} \vdash \mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is a fibration (Grothendieck).
I am interested in investigating double fibration for my PhD, I need to understand firstly the intuition behind the link of geometric morphisms and fibrations. Has this been studied before for double categories?
